# Hyperlinks.add VBA

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I'm programming in VBA. I want to create hyperlinks using `hyperlink.add` method of the ActiveSheet object but *it doesn't work.*

Here is my code:

```
'set the link
Dim mainsheet As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set mainsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(rowNumb + 2)


mainsheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=mainsheet.Range(rowTablecontent + rowNumb, colTablecontent + 3), _
                Address:="", _
                SubAddress:=ws.Name & "!A1", _
                TextToDisplay:="Link"
```

**Code description:**

I have a Mainsheet, on which I have a Table of Contents and a button for starting the macro. When starting the macro, the program imports 4 Files (each has one sheet and equals one sheet in the mainworkbook. With the information of this 4 files there are about 500 sheets which are going to be generated.
The point is: now i want to have a table of contents. for each sheet a link in the mainsheet.

Variable:

- rowTablecontent --> Row on the top of the content table
- colTablecontent --> Column on the left of the content table
- rowNumb         --> Rowcounter on the inputfile

I used the same code in another program, where it worked, so I don't know what I did wrong.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

**Important Info Copied From Comments**

> In my project I have 4 Input files/sheets. And there it works. But on the autmatically created sheets, it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the value in `rowNumb`? Make sure Sheets with that index exist.

Comment: what *doesn't work*? Can you be more specific? Do you get an error message? What is it? What is `rowNumb` and how many sheets do you have?

Comment: @Santosh it DOES exist

Comment: @mehow When i'm clicking on the link there is an alert: "Bezug ist ungültig"(in english: "Reference is not valid") and and I have enough sheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned what error you are getting. There could be many errors. Some of them are.

1. Activesheet is not the one you think it is.
2. The selection is not a range
3. Sheet doesn't exist
4. rowNumb is not a valid number
5. Sheet/workbook could be protected (Thanks Sam)

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rowNumb As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the relevant number
    rowNumb = 1

    If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rowNumb + 1)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Sheet doesn't exist"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, _
                                   Address:="", _
                                   SubAddress:=ws.Name & "!A1", _
                                   TextToDisplay:="Link"
    Else
        MsgBox "InValid Range Object"
    End If
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS**

> But on the autmatically created sheets, it doesn't work.

You missed my first point. `Activesheet is not the one you think it is.`

Here is a sample on how to add hyperlink to a newly created file. This demonstration shows how to add hyperlink to `Sheet1 A1` of newly created file. The hyperlink will address `Sheet2 A1` of the newly created file.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ws1.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws1.Range("A1"), _
                                       Address:="", _
                                       SubAddress:=ws2.Name & "!A1", _
                                       TextToDisplay:="Link"
End Sub
```

I am not doing any error handling. i am sure you can take care of that.

Comment: Sheet could be protected as well. Sheet name could contain a space (that may still cause errors with your code I think, (not tested)).

Comment: Like I said there can be many errors :) I just listed a few :) However I will still add your comment.

Comment: @Sam How can I check if my sheets are protected?

Comment: @InformatikBabo: Press `ATL + T + P + P` If you get a prompt to unprotect worksheet then you will know it is protected. Do you get any error with my code?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes. In my project I have 4 Input files/sheets. And there it works. But on the autmatically created sheets, it doesn't work. And nothig happens withy the keyboard combination ATL + T + P + P (i have office 2010).

Comment: @InformatikBabo: Please answer my question... What error error do you get? Also wait... `But on the autmatically created files`??? Do you mean creating new file via code and then adding the hyperlink to it?

Comment: @SiddharthRout "Bezug ist ungültig" (in english: "Reference is not valid")

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes thats exactly what I meant.

Comment: @InformatikBabo Based on your comment, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Does it matter if I use range or cell at the anchor?

Comment: @InformatikBabo: No it doesn't. So `ws1.Range("A1")` can be written as `ws.cells(1,1)` as well.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for your helping. But it's still not working. It's always the same error: Reference is not valid

Comment: @InformatikBabo: can you please update your question with the latest code that you are using? including the part where you are creating the new workbook.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I will update the question right now, but I did never create a new workbook. I opened a new for moving its sheets in my main workbook and after the import I only worked in my mainworkbook

Comment: @InformatikBabo: I am even more confused with the latest update :) Well, I have to step out for couple of hours. Will come back and look at this question. In the meantime can you describe in detail what you exactly want? Also ensure that all variable are declared and explained in your question so that we don't have to ask about what each and every variable means.

Comment: @InformatikBabo: I don't give up fast but I feel I am about to do that in this question :) Sigh... Please read my last comment again... What is `rowTablecontent` What is `rowNumb` What is `ColTablecontent`? I am loosing the interest in the question... I can see 4 close votes on the question and 3 of them actually point to this question being `unclear` Well, if you don't explain it nicely then I am afraid that this question will get closed...

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have the variable names described. Is it clear now? :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have the solution!! The sheet name needs to be inside inverted commas.


SubAddress:="'" & ws.Name & "'" & "!A1", _

Comment: @InformatikBabo: Do you know that the code that I pasted above is tested and tried?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, but it didn't work in THIS project anyway. But thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout It must have inverted commas, because the sheet names sometimes have whitespaces.

Comment: @InformatikBabo: Glad your problem is solved...

Answer (score 1):

I tested this, it worked on Excel 2007, you could try?

#### EDIT to approach to your question.

```
Sub sofMacro20000463(ByVal rowNumb)
'
' Dim rowNumb
'
' rowNumb = ActiveCell.Row
'
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", _
    SubAddress:=Sheets(rowNumb + 1).Name & "!A1", _
    TextToDisplay:="Link"
'
End Sub


Sub sofMacroDoIt()
'
  Dim rowNumb
'
  rowNumb = ActiveCell.Row
'
  sofMacro20000463 rowNumb
'
End Sub
```

This permits navigating to Worksheet in function of row index from the activesheet.

sofMacro20000463() can be called with other parameters.

Comment: I don't think `rowNumb` is actually a row number. It's used as a sheet index. It's poorly named.

Comment: One can switch Sheets using index from 1, such as 1,2,3 without requiring sheet name.

Comment: @Sam No, it's a row number, but from an other Sheet.

Comment: @jacouh I don't understand what you mean with it.

Comment: On clicking on the link, you go to cell A1 of another Worksheet, this is what I wanted to express. This was just a guess.

Comment: @jacouh ok. but your example can't work. In my function i have rowNumb as parameter. and the rest is the same as I already have.

Comment: I just confirm that it works with me.

Comment: @jacouh okay. it doesn't work on excel2010...