# Looking to get the audit log values as hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

```
'This is my code and I want the values retrieved by this code as linkable .Range("F" & NR).Value = Hyperlink("#'!sh.Name'!" & CELL("Target.Address"), "Target.Address")

'Below is the full code
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim NR As Long
Dim CELL As Range, Hyperlink As String
If sh.Name = "AuditLog" Then Exit Sub     

Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Sheets("AuditLog")
        NR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("B" & NR).Value = Environ("UserName")
        .Range("C" & NR).Value = Environ("ComputerName")
        .Range("D" & NR).Value = Now
        .Range("E" & NR).Value = sh.Name
'This code will retrieve values from the changed cell, I want this as a hyperlink to the value changed in another worksheet
        .Range("F" & NR).Value = Hyperlink("#'!sh.Name'!" & CELL("Target.Address"), "Target.Address")
        .Range("G" & NR).Value = Prior Val
        .Range("H" & NR).Value = Target(1).Value
        NR = NR + 1
    End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please let us know what your question is or where the code is not working. BTW, this is not the code which you are using, right? Especially the line `.Range("G" & NR).Value = Prior Val` shouldn't work as it is.

Comment: Hi Ralph, This code is .Range("G" & NR).Value = PriorVal as it was not allowing me to post my code. This code is a piece of my entire code set what i am looking here is, if anybody changes all cell value in the worksheet it will get captured in the Audit log and the cell need to be hyperlink, so that the person who is auditing the log should go directly to the location where we have changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperlinks.add VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000463/hyperlinks-add-vba)

Comment: Try to incorporate any of the suggested solutions provided on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx

Comment: Thank you Ralph, i got this fixed by using the code .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("AuditLog").Cells(NR, 6), Address:="", SubAddress:=sh.Name & "!" & Target.Address, TextToDisplay:=sh.Name & "!" & Target.Address which even you have mentioned here, the only problem i am facing now is is the name of worksheet has space this code is not working. In my code I need to fix at this point "SubAddress:=sh.Name"

Comment: Wrap the sheet name between apostrophes like so: `SubAddress:= "'" & sh.Name & "'"`

Comment: It works Ralph, Thank you again!

Comment: Please post the complete answer down below for everybody else to read and as a future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
' This code will help to traverse back to the cell where the changes was made to get captured under Audit Log
Option Explicit
Public PriorVal As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim NR As Long
    With Sheets("AuditLog")
        NR = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Range("B" & NR).Value = Environ("UserName")
        .Range("C" & NR).Value = Environ("ComputerName")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection(1).Value = "" Then
        PriorVal = "Blank"
    Else
        PriorVal = Selection(1).Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim NR As Long
Dim CELL As Range
If sh.Name = "AuditLog" Then Exit Sub     'allows you to edit the log sheet

Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Sheets("AuditLog")
        NR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("B" & NR).Value = Environ("UserName")
        .Range("C" & NR).Value = Environ("ComputerName")
        .Range("D" & NR).Value = Now
        .Range("E" & NR).Value = sh.Name
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("AuditLog").Cells(NR, 6), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sh.Name & "'" & "!" & Target.Address, TextToDisplay:=sh.Name & "!" & Target.Address
        .Range("G" & NR).Value = PriorVal
        .Range("H" & NR).Value = Target(1).Value
        NR = NR + 1
    End With
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```